# Change current song from lock screen

Tags: lock-screen, spotify, media-buttons

We have a Sonos box in our office which is connected to my laptop. Music source is Spotify for Ubuntu.

Usually I try to skip songs which aren't "office compatible" (like when it's too edgy or so). I'd like my colleagues to allow to skip the song when I'm not at my desk. For this my keyboard provides those media keys (keyborad itself is a Logitech K750). Unfortunately they won't work when the screen is locked - only the volume buttons work, but not those for Play/Pause/Skip. Is there some way I can enable these to work from the lock screen?